# How to spy on a method which is called inside componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to spy on a method which is called inside componentDidMount. The method itself resides inside another file. Here is what i tried so far:

```
import apicall from './AnotherFile'
class MyComponent {
    componentDidMount() {
        apicall()
    }
    <other code ->
}
```

Test:

```
const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent/>);
const instance = wrapper.instance();
jest.spyOn(instance, 'apicall');
instance.componentDidMount();
expect(instance.apicall).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

It gives an error:

`Cannot spy the apicall property because it is not a function; undefined given instead`

Any idea how this can be achieved ?

Comment: try to copy to a local attribute: _apicall = apicall, and then, use '_apicall' in spyOn()

Comment: but that solution in incomplete if you don't use this._apicall() in componentDidMount()... probably the spyOn will prepare a wrapper for that local function

Comment: did not understand, can u site an example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this:

1. **Mock the import in your test file**: By using `jest.mock`, Jest will intercept an import and create a mock version when it's used in the component file:

   ```
   // MyComponent.test.js
   import apicall from './AnotherFile'

   jest.mock('./AnotherFile');

   it('makes API call', () => {
     const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);
     expect(apicall).toHaveBeenCalled();
   });
   ```

No need to get the `instance`, no need to manually call `componentDidMount`, that will happen when you `mount(<MyComponent />)`. Note: if `apicall` should return a value or a promise, you can provide a mock value:

```
// Mock a response if your componentDidMount calls `apicall.then()`...
apicall.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve('some value'));
// Mock a rejected Promise to test error cases
apicall.mockImplementation(() => Promise.reject('Oh no!'));
```

2. **Dependency injection:** Pass the `apicall` function into your component. You can make it default to the actual `apicall` you import, but in the test you can pass in a mock function:

   ```
   // MyComponent.js
   import apicall as realApiCall from './AnotherFile'

   class MyComponent extends Component {

     static defaultProps = {
       apicall: realApiCall
     }

     componentDidMount() {
       // This will call the real apicall if you don't provide
       // a prop: <MyComponent /> ... but allows you to inject
       // a mock apicall function in tests.
       this.props.apicall()
     }
     <other code ->
   }

   // MyComponent.test.js
   const apicall = jest.fn();
   const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent apicall={apicall} />);
   expect(apicall).toHaveBeenCalled();
   ```

Comment: same error : ` Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function` when i tried Method 1

Answer (score -1):

You mock the function that was imported. Try this

```
    import * as dependency from '../AnotherFile';

    describe('MyComponent', () => {
        it('test apicall', () => {
            dependency.apicall = jest.fn();

            const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);
            wrapper.instance().componentDidMount();

            expect(dependency.apicall).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
```

Comment: getting this error : Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.

Comment: Try removing the parenthesis like so `dependency.apicall = jest.fn;`